# How to manipulate Google maps iframe to get the preferred longitude and latitude

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

currently working on a school project and I have been able to come up with some part of it that involves getting the location and device details of an IP.

I've been able to work with an API and got the JSON data into tables with html and PHP and this shows the information needed in a table.

[img of the data and map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alV1Z.png)

I'll like to give it a final touch by adding Google maps but the problem I face now is **how to replace the latitude and longitude from the Google maps iframe with the latitude and longitude from the tables I already have so I also get the location on a map** and not just in text.

I've tried to programmatically solve this problem using js but still having issues,

```
<iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=6.61526,3.5069 &hl=en&z=15&amp;output=embed" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

replacing the lat and long in the iframe with data from the long and lat data from the api instead so ones an IP is searched for it automatically parses the data to the src which then opens the map with the location.

```
      <tr>
      <th scope="row">' . $json->query . '</th>
      <td>' . $json->country . ' (' . $json->countryCode . ')</td>
      <td>' . $json->regionName . '</td>
      <td>' . $json->city . '</td>
      <td>' . $json->zip . '</td>
      <td>' . $json->lat . '</td>
      <td>' . $json->lon . '</td>
      <td>' . $json->timezone . '</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what the issue actually is? Your code doesn’t seem to make an attempt at building the requisite `iframe` `src` URL at all - this should be a simple string concatenation of values you’ve already output to the DOM - where *specifically* are you getting stuck in implementing this? Without seeing what you’ve written so far to meet this new requirement this runs afoul of our [ask] guidance which prescribes you make an attempt at resolving your issue/requirement before posting here.

Answer (score -1):

I think using if else statements that uses conditions to check what type of longitude and latitude already exists in the database and replaces them.

I'm still learning though, just decided to chip in something.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).